# right click mouse to paste on a richtextbox vc++ windows forms

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, click, mouse

I am searching on how to implement a mouse down right click to paste data from a buffer into a richtextbox with visual c++ windows forms. My richtextbox is working but I can only paste data from buffer using shift+insert key.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

Changed the RichTextBox to TextBox and use the code:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender System::EventArgs^  e) {
             String^ fileName = "output.txt";
             StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
             sw->WriteLine(textBox1->Text);
             sw->Close();
```

}

The "paste" option is automatically available on the textbox (multi-line in my case). I think this is not possible with RichTextBox without heavy coding?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a right click menu which can paste the clipboard's text to the RichTextBox?

1) Add a ContextMenuStrip (contextMenuStrip1)
2) Add a ToolStripMenuItem and name it paste (pasteToolStripMenuItem)
3) Set richTextBox1's ContextMenuStrip to contextMenuStrip1
4) Double-click the pasteToolStripMenuItem

```
private: System::Void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    richTextBox1->Paste();
}
```